# AngularJS Timer doesn't work with Ajax Data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I have to pages, where one is **screen.php** witch shows a table with data pulled from **data.php** with 2 seconds interval.

In screen.php  data is being pulled like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
      setInterval(function() {
   $('.container').load('data.php');
      }, 2000);
 });
```

After this i have made a AngularJS Timer app :

```
    angular.module('MyApp', ['timer'])
            .controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.timerRunning = true;
                $scope.startTimer = function (){
                    $scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
                    $scope.timerRunning = true;
                };
                $scope.stopTimer = function (){
                    $scope.$broadcast('timer-stop');
                    $scope.timerRunning = false;
                };
                $scope.$on('timer-stopped', function (event, args) {
                    console.log('timer-stopped args = ', args);
                });

            }]);
```

The data returned bu the first script (from data.php) is in this format:

```
XXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX {{minutes}} : {{seconds}}
```

Witch should convert the {{minutes}} : {{seconds}} , in 00:00 , since in the datatest.php the filed is :

```
<timer start-time="<?php echo $dt; ?>">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
```

I know this might be a real noob question but better ask .

I have included the AngularJS in the **screen.php** page, and makred the boday with :

```
body ng-app="MyApp"
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated

P.S. To whoever is down voting the question, pls live a comment on why, so I dont make the same mistakes again.

Comment: Use `$interval`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Some piratical example you could give as I have read the doc, and I am not succeeding in doing this, please

Comment: Tried modifing the script like:
`        angular.module('MyApp', ['timer'])
                .controller('MyAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $interval) {
              
                $scope.Timer = $interval(function () {
                    //Display the current time.
                     $scope.timerRunning = true;
                }, 2000);



                }]); `   @eh.

Comment: For whoever might be interested ,  i ditched AngularJS Timer at all, and just pulled back the already calculated time in min and sec with php, so it refreshes every 2 secs, and its the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever might be interested , i ditched AngularJS Timer at all, and just pulled back the already calculated time in min and sec with php, so it refreshes every 2 secs, and its the same

```
    $ms=(strtotime($timeNow) * 1000)-(strtotime($row[6]) * 1000);
    $time=floor($ms/60000).':'.floor(($ms%60000)/1000);
```